# OSX crash happening on system libraries and no sign of my app

Tags: macos, stack-trace, crash-reports

A crash is occurring in my app but the crash report only shows system libraries. It is clear that my app is provoking the issue but because 1) of its size and 2) there isn't sign of any of my libraries in the stack trace, I can't figure out where it is happening. As far as I know it is related with NSUrlConnection but it is being used in lots of places.

Does any body knows how can I used Atos or lldb to symbolicate when my app is NOT being mentioned in the stack trace?

Below is the stack.

Thanks

```
 Thread 33:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader  Dispatch queue: com.apple.CFFileDescriptor
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9d3a2add __CFFileDescriptorEnableCallBacks_block_invoke + 13
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9b13440b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9b1359f2 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 74
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9d3a2ab4 CFFileDescriptorEnableCallBacks + 180
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9d42cdaa constructCFFD + 122
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9d36e48e fileOpen + 238
6   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9d3626a8 _CFStreamOpen + 120
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9d36e37f CFReadStreamOpen + 95
8   com.apple.CFNetwork             0x00007fff911b27fe FileURLProtocol::_protocolInterface_startLoad(_CFCachedURLResponse const*) + 578
9   com.apple.CFNetwork             0x00007fff91041350 ___ZN19URLConnectionLoader27_private_ScheduleOriginLoadEPK12NSURLRequestPK20_CFCachedURLResponse_block_invoke_2 + 61
10  com.apple.CFNetwork             0x00007fff910412f1 ___ZNK19URLConnectionLoader25withExistingProtocolAsyncEU13block_pointerFvP11URLProtocolE_block_invoke + 25
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9b13440b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9b142039 _dispatch_block_invoke + 474
13  com.apple.CFNetwork             0x00007fff9104017c RunloopBlockContext::_invoke_block(void const*, void*) + 24
14  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9d33ad74 CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
15  com.apple.CFNetwork             0x00007fff91040075 RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 137
16  com.apple.CFNetwork             0x00007fff9103ff16 MultiplexerSource::perform() + 282
17  com.apple.CFNetwork             0x00007fff9103fd38 MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 72
18  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9d398881 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
19  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9d377fbc __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
20  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9d3774df __CFRunLoopRun + 927
21  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9d376ed8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
22  com.apple.CFNetwork             0x00007fff9101aa6d +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 412
23  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9b195e64 __NSThread__start__ + 1351
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9997a99d _pthread_body + 131
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9997a91a _pthread_start + 168
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff99978351 thread_start + 13
```